# A cohomology associated to a Riemannian manifold

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, cohomology, group-cohomology

Let $N$ be a compact Riemanian manifold and $G$ be its isometry group. Let $M=\chi^{\infty}(N)$ be the space of smooth vector fields on $N$. There is a natural right action of $G$ on $M$ with $X.g=g^*(X),\; g\in G, X\in M$, the push forward of $X$ under the isometry $g$. So $M$ is a $G$ module.

> How can one express  the group  cohomologies $H^n(G,M)$ explicitely?Is there  a 
>    reference  which contain such  computations? What can be said about a  riemannian manifold whose all cohomology groups  $H^n(G,M)$ vanish?

**Edit:** according to the comment of  Neal I  understand the  following part of the previous version  is  a trivial question:

<s>Does this sequence of cohomologies determine the geometry of $N$? Namely is it true to say that two nonisometric metrics on $N$ give two different cohomology sequence?</s>

Comment: Most metrics should have trivial isometry groups.

Comment: @Neal  thanks for your comment. Is there a reference who  computed this cohomology in the non rigid case, e.g for constant curvature?

Comment: I don't have a reference handy, but I think even for constant curvature one often has trivial isometry group? (Euclidean tori do not.) I would start exploring with hyperbolic surfaces, c.f. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/222154/isometry-group-of-a-compact-hyperbolic-surface